# How to fire OnClick event in nested panels with ModalPopupExtender?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, updatepanel, modalpopupextender

I have the following scenario:

`UpdatePanel1` -> `UpdatePanel2` -> `UpdatePanel3`:

Inside it I have a `GridView` with a following column definition:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="img_btnEdit" runat="server" AlternateText="Edit" 
        CausesValidation="false" Height="15px" OnClientClick='<%#Eval("TranValueId", "PopulateEditTransValuesMDPP({0}); return false;") %>' 
        ImageUrl="~/Images/document_edit.png" Width="15px" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

When clicked, a `ModalPopupExtender` should open, but first I need to retrieve the boundfield of the clicked row.

**JS function:**

```
function PopulateEditTransValuesMDPP(id) {

    var btPopupLoad = document.getElementById('<%= btPopupLoad.ClientID %>');
    var hdnlblModalPopuphelper = document.getElementById('<%= hdnlblModalPopuphelper.ClientID %>');

    if (id != null) {
        hdnlblModalPopuphelper.innerHTML = id;
    }

    btPopupLoad.click();
}
```

Here is the rest of the **HTML code** that resides in the same `UpdatePanel` as the `GridView`:

```
<asp:Label ID="hdnlblModalPopuphelper" runat="server" Text="" style="display:none;"></asp:Label> 
<asp:Button ID="btPopupLoad" runat="server" Text="Load" OnClick="btPopupLoad_Click" style="display:none;"  /> 
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="modppOpen" runat="server" TargetControlID="btPopupLoad" 
    PopupControlID="pnlModPPDefaultValueEditing"  BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" OkControlID="btnCloseModalPopup"
    DropShadow="true" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnlModPPDefaultValueEditing" runat="server" CssClass="aspnetForm" Width="80%"> 
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpanEditDefaultValue" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers> 
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSaveEditingTransValueDefaultValue" />
    </Triggers>
(...)
```

**Problem Description:**
Everything works fine, except that the `OnClick` Event (the server side event) of the `btPopupLoad` is not triggered!

The only way I made the `OnClick` event to get fired was by setting the `UseSubmitBehaviour="false"` in its definition but that's causing a **postback** and the `ModalPopup` dissapears. 
So basically I want the `OnClick Event` to be triggered and in the same time keep the `ModalPopup` still opened.

Help, please?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by myself so if anyone ever runs into this, this is how it worked for me:

Instead of

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="img_btnEdit" runat="server" AlternateText="Edit" 
        CausesValidation="false" Height="15px" OnClientClick='<%#Eval("TranValueId", "PopulateEditTransValuesMDPP({0}); return false;") %>' 
        ImageUrl="~/Images/document_edit.png" Width="15px" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

(which uses a hacky way of opening a modal popup anyway) just do this:

**HTML**

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="img_btnEdit" runat="server" AlternateText="Edit" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" CommandName="Editing"  
CausesValidation="false" Height="15px" 
ImageUrl="~/Images/document_edit.png" Width="15px" />
```

**C#:**

```
protected void gvTransValues_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Editing")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row = gvTransValues.Rows[index];

        //do whatever you need here

        modppOpen.Show();
    }
}
```

What I basically did was to replace the whole hacky way of using hidden buttons or labels and just prompt the modalpopup straight from the click of the button using `CommandName` and `CommandArguments` of the `RowCommand` event of the `gridview`.